# Solutions of $x\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} + \psi = f(x)e^{-2\pi i y}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I stumbled across the following PDE for a function $\psi(x, y)$:
$$
x\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} + \psi = f(x)e^{-2\pi i y}
$$
where $f(z)$ is some arbitrary function. I was wondering if anyone knows anything about equations of this kind or how to solve them. Separation of variables didn't seem to work, so I'm fresh out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple says
$$
\psi(x,y) = \frac{1}{x}\left(\int_a^xf(t)\exp\left(\frac{-2\pi i y t}{x}\right)\;dt+F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)
$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function.

Comment: Thanks - that's reassuring.

Answer (score 1):

$x\dfrac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}+\psi=f(x)e^{-2\pi iy}$

$x\dfrac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}=f(x)e^{-2\pi iy}-\psi$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x$ , letting $x(0)=1$ , we have $x=e^t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=y_0e^t=y_0x$

$\dfrac{d\psi}{dt}=f(x)e^{-2\pi iy}-\psi=f(e^t)e^{-2\pi iy_0e^t}-\psi$

$\dfrac{d\psi}{dt}+\psi=f(e^t)e^{-2\pi iy_0e^t}$

I.F. $=e^{\int dt}=e^t$

$\therefore\dfrac{d}{dt}(e^t\psi)=f(e^t)e^{t-2\pi iy_0e^t}$

$e^t\psi=\int f(e^t)e^{t-2\pi iy_0e^t}~dt$

$e^t\psi=\int_0^tf(e^s)e^{s-2\pi iy_0e^s}~ds+C$

$\psi=e^{-t}\int_0^tf(e^s)e^{s-2\pi iy_0e^s}~ds+Ce^{-t}$

$u(0)=F(y_0)$ :

$C=F(y_0)$

$\therefore\psi(x,y)=e^{-t}\int_0^tf(e^s)e^{s-2\pi iy_0e^s}~ds+F(y_0)e^{-t}$

$\psi(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{x}\int_0^{\ln x}f(e^s)e^se^{-\frac{2\pi iye^s}{x}}~ds+\dfrac{1}{x}F\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$

$\psi(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{x}\int_0^{\ln x}f(e^s)e^{-\frac{2\pi iye^s}{x}}~d(e^s)+\dfrac{1}{x}F\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$

$\psi(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{x}\int_1^xf(t)e^{-\frac{2\pi iyt}{x}}~dt+\dfrac{1}{x}F\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$